# iPad cuts off content in both landscape and portrait

Tags: html, css, ipad, responsive-design

I'm having issues with the rendering of a simple page on iPad in both landscape and portrait views.

I've attached a screenshot of the issue. You can see in the top right that the navigation elements are showing up to the right of the 'cut off,' but the graphical elements just stop randomly. So while it's being cut off in some ways, it's not in others.

I have what seems to be a pretty run of the mill viewport definition:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1.0">`

Any ideas why this would happen? Thanks-[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am stunned why no one answered this till now! I can see that the problem still persists so I am guessing you have not yet figured out the solution.

This is a very basic error that is faced by CSS beginners. The overflow is set to visible in your media queries, but the nested divs in the body element do not have this property. So the background components are getting restricted in the header and the footer. The links are still visible because they have a fixed width. You need to make the design more responsive so that there is no need for overflow:visible on body element and the body properly nests everything on the page. A proper responsive design will not suffer from these basic failures.

Let me know if you need further clarifications.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, but next time try to be less condescending towards developers that may have not run into this problem before or are just learning the language.